# MVVM Textbox gotFocus binding to a method is not working

Tags: c#, .net, binding, textbox

I have a method in my view model. How I can bind this method to textbox.gotfocus property.

My XAML part is:

```
<TextBox Style=
    "{StaticResource TextBoxHadnigPanel}"
    GotFocus="{Binding GotFocusCustomerNameMethod}"
    LostFocus="{Binding LostFocusCustomerNameMethod}"
    x:Name="TextBoxCustomerName"
    Grid.Row="0"
    Grid.Column="1"
    MaxLength="16"
    Margin="10" />
```

How to bind this `LostFocus` and `GotFocus` properties?

Anyone?
Thanks in advance

Comment: How is the implementation of the method in your ViewModel? Are they implemented with ICommand?

Comment: No. I don't have a button here. So I didn't use ICommand here

Answer (score 1):

You can't bind a method in WPF.

Alternative: You can use a Behavior for a TextBox with MVVM.

You need a reference to System.Windows.Interactivity to achieve this.

```
public class TextBoxFocusBehavior : Behavior<TextBox>
{
    #region Overrides of Behavior

    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        AssociatedObject.GotFocus += AssociatedObject_GotFocus;
        AssociatedObject.LostFocus += AssociatedObject_LostFocus;
        base.OnAttached();
    }

    private void AssociatedObject_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //TODO Your LostFocus Method here.
    }

    private void AssociatedObject_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //TODO Your GotFocus Method here.
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Xaml:

You need a reference in the xaml file:

```
xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
xmlns:behaviors="clr-namespace:YourNamespace"



<TextBox Style="{StaticResource TextBoxHadnigPanel}"
    x:Name="TextBoxCustomerName"
    Grid.Row="0"
    Grid.Column="1"
    MaxLength="16"
    Margin="10">
    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <behaviors:TextBoxFocusBehavior />
    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
</TextBox>
```